# How can I change the version of python being used by IDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, osx-yosemite, python-idle

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed on my mac.
 IDLE is using the latter, how can I change that ?
I looked for idle in python2.7 folder under */Library/Python* but all I can find under *Python2.7* is a folder having the name *site-packages*.

Comment: Hit Cmd-Space and type IDLE. Note that multiple versions appear. Pick the one you want.

Comment: I get only the IDLE version running python 3.4

Comment: Then re-run the installer from python.org

Comment: The IDLE files are in Lib/idlelib, beside Lib/site-packages and other folders.  It is possible that 2.7 was installed without tkinter, idlelib, and turtle.

Answer (score -1):

you may try by changing the system variables....I don't know particularly about mac but in window we can do so.You may refer the following link.

=======================
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX6mc9l6tY4